# can't load model of keras

Tags: python, keras

i am trying to load my trained model but i can't

```
from keras.models import load_model
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2

# load the trained model and label binarizer from disk
print("[INFO] loading model and label binarizer...")
model = load_model("model\\activity.model")
lb = pickle.loads(open("model\\lb.pickle", "rb").read())
```

Error message....

```
[INFO] loading model and label binarizer...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0c9553a7156e> in <module>()
      1 # load the trained model and label binarizer from disk
      2 print("[INFO] loading model and label binarizer...")
----> 3 model = load_model("model\\activity.model")
      4 lb = pickle.loads(open("model\\lb.pickle", "rb").read())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    417     f = h5dict(filepath, 'r')
    418     try:
--> 419         model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
    420     finally:
    421         if opened_new_file:


ValueError: ('Invalid `distribution` argument: expected one of {"normal", "uniform"} but got', 'truncated_normal')
```

Comment: Might be an issue with mismatched versions. Which version of keras did you build the model in and which version are you using right now?

Comment: its issue of versions.....Thanks man...